# Inappbrowser error if the page redirects

Tags: cordova, redirect, phonegap, inappbrowser

I'm trying to open  https://www.mywebsite.com/help in inappbrowser which then redirects to https://www.mywebsite.com/help/residential-customer (assume it is third party page where I do not have dev control).
Im hiding the inappbrowser so that I can show a loader till the page loads

**Issue:**

After loadstart, loadstop was not triggered, in some devices loaderror is triggered!

```
var path="https://www.mywebsite.com/help";

var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(path, '_blank', 'toolbarposition=top,closebuttoncaption=Back,location=no,hardwareback=no,hidden=yes');

showLoadingIcon();


//loadstop event
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
    //todo
});

//loadstop event
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
    hideLoadingIcon();
    ref.show();
});

//exit event
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
    hideLoadingIcon();
    ref.close();
});

//loaderror event
ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) {
    hideLoadingIcon();
    ref.close();
    showMessage("not happening!");
});
```

I understood that this is an issue with the third party page but I want my app to handle it rather than crashing.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not hide it!**

I could not find the right answer for this issue despite the thread being open since years in some forums.

However, I found that not hiding the inappbrowser partially cures this issue.
And I was able to inject a spinner to the inappbrowser for improving the user experience by avoiding the awkward white screen.

**Custom Spinner**

following solution has many alternatives, one can use an html file 'spinner.html' instead of  hard-coding, but this specific approach is working across platform (nexus 5, pixel 1/2, iphone 6,7)

```
//use some really slow page for testing
var path="https://www.facebook.com/";

//if you have a spinner.html, you can load that instead of path here in inappbrowser, but make sure it works in all devices.

var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(path, '_blank', 'toolbarposition=top,closebuttoncaption=Back,location=no,hardwareback=no');

//spinner html
var spinner ="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1'><style>.loader {position: absolute;    margin-left: -2em;    left: 50%;    top: 50%;    margin-top: -2em;    border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;    border-radius: 50%;    border-top: 5px solid #3498db;    width: 50px;    height: 50px;    -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;    animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;}@-webkit-keyframes spin {  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); } 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }}@keyframes spin {  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }  100% { transform:rotate(360deg); }}</style></head><body><div class='loader'></div></body></html>";

//intended webpage is loaded here (facebook)
ref.executeScript({code: "(function() {document.write(\""+spinner+"\");window.location.href='"+path+"';})()"});

//loadstop event
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
    //nothing specific needed for spinner                        
});

//loadstop event
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
    //nothing specific needed for spinner
});
```

spinner will be overwritten by the actual page once it starts loading.